# Tool/dataset for matching first names and nicknames

Tags: dataset, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to identify the same individuals in a large dataset where sometimes the individuals may be listed by their full first name (e.g., "Michael Douglas") and sometimes by its nickname (e.g., "Mike Douglas"). Does anyone know of a dataset that has (at least) English first names and their corresponding common nicknames? Or a tool that will do such matching for you? I searched for a while and couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps. I could not check the content, but it says that it provides a csv mapping names and nicknames.

https://github.com/carltonnorthern/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!